# "SELECT column_name FROM table_name" unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm using the sample AdventureWorksLT database on Azure SQLdb. I get the following result when I query `SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]`, which is expected.

[image]

But when I query `SELECT CustomerID FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]`, or `SELECT TOP 7 CustomerID FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]`, I was expecting the CustomerID column results to be already in a sorted way just like in the first screenshot, But instead I get this unexpected unsorted result like below.

[image]

What is the reason behind this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Use ORDER BY if you want a specific order.

Comment: I know, but my question is what is the reason for the unexpected results.

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan, why do you care if you know that the only way to get a guaranteed order is by using `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Check This it might help you :
 https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/executing-select-query-using-top-without-order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's unexpected behavior it's because of the false assumption there is an underlying physical ordering of the rows.  There isn't one.  SQL is an interpreted language.  When a `SELECT` statement is executed without `ORDER BY` the interpreter decides which rows to return.  Many times the rows are returned in the desired order but it cannot be relied upon because the interpreter makes NO GUARANTEES about the row ordering.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unexpected behavior.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  A result set is *unordered*, unless you explicitly have an `ORDER BY` in the outermost query.

Add an `ORDER BY` to get the results you want:

```
SELECT TOP 7 CustomerID
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

If you do not have an `ORDER BY` and the results happen to look like they are ordered, that is just a coincidence.  If you want to guarantee the ordering, you need `ORDER BY`.

Comment: But why are they ordered when I query select *

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan , without `ORDER BY` the returned order depends on the execution plan, which can vary for each execution and other factors as well. See this post as to why [order by is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/).

Comment: @DanGuzman Very Well. But the result for the second query is always the same, regardless of whenever or how many times I execute it.

Comment: yes but it's not guaranteed to do so repeatedly.  If the optimizer decides differently then it doesn't owe you an explanation because it didn't (and doesn't) come with a guarantee.  It'll just change how the rows are returned.